# python: validate kerberos ticket

Tags: python, linux, kerberos

I'm wondering - if anyone has an elegant solution to checking for a valid Kerberos ticket using Python. I'm not seeing anyway with `kinit` or `klist` that will show if a ticket is expired with a return code but I could run `klist` and use a regex for the output .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two options: the first is to use 'klist -s' and check the return code. The nicer option is to use the [python-krbV](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-krbV) module:

```
import krbV

def has_ticket():
    '''
    Checks to see if the user has a valid ticket.
    '''
    ctx = krbV.default_context()
    cc = ctx.default_ccache()
    try:
        princ = cc.principal()
        retval = True
    except krbV.Krb5Error:
        retval = False

    return retval
```

Comment: Note that these are not equivalent: klist -s also exits non-zero if there is a ccache with a TGT, but the TGT has expired. The krbV code above does not check whether the ticket has expired; only that there is a ccache at all (by reading the default principal from it). And, the OP specifically asked about ticket expiration.

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to check exit status of 'klist -s' 
looks shorter and does not use krbV:

```
import subprocess

def has_kerberos_ticket():
    return True if subprocess.call(['klist', '-s']) == 0 else False
```

Comment: More succinctly, `return not not subprocess.call(['klist', '-s'])`?

Comment: Since I had no end of troubles getting krbV to compile right for Python 3.6, I really think this is the better methodology for my uses.